# how to prevent bootstrap modal popup from opening login screen in it when session gets expired in MVC5

Tags: jquery, model-view-controller

I have used form authentication in my application. when the session expired I am redirecting the user to the login page.
it workes fine for normal view. but when I open modal popup with a partial view using ajax call and if idle for some time. and click on the button, I am getting login page inside the modal popup.

Can anyone help me to solve this issue? Thanks in advance.

Please look at code below,

jquery to open the modal popup

```
  $("#btnCreatePackage").on("click", function () {
        var url = $(this).data("url");
        $.get(url, function (data) {
            $('#createPackageContainer').html(data);
            $('#createPackageModal').modal('show');
        });
    });
```

ajax call method which returns partial view

```
    [HttpGet]
    public ActionResult AddPackage()
    {
       //code here

        return View("_PartialEditPackage", objModelView);
    }
```

Comment: Give us your code. what have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have to use an authorize filter for ajax requests and then handle it client side.  Please see the code below.  Credit to Sergey Zwezdin [Handling Authentication-specific issues for AJAX](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/655086/Handling-authentication-specific-issues-for-AJAX-c)

```
   public class ApplicationAuthorizeAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
{
    protected override void HandleUnauthorizedRequest(AuthorizationContext filterContext)
    {
        var httpContext = filterContext.HttpContext;
        var request = httpContext.Request;
        var response = httpContext.Response;
        var user = httpContext.User;

        if (request.IsAjaxRequest())
        {
            if (user.Identity.IsAuthenticated == false)
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized;
            else
                response.StatusCode = (int)HttpStatusCode.Forbidden;

            response.SuppressFormsAuthenticationRedirect = true;
            response.End();
        }

        base.HandleUnauthorizedRequest(filterContext);
    }
}



 $.ajax({
  url: url,
  success: function(data) {
     $('#createPackageContainer').html(data);
     $('#createPackageModal').modal('show');       
  },
  error: function(XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) { 
    if (XMLHttpRequest.status == 401) {
      //redirect window to login page
    }
  }
});
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59785362/how-to-prevent-bootstrap-modal-popup-from-opening-login-screen-in-it-when-sessio/59788485#59788485
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Just set a flag to check user is logged in or not and get it on ajax response.
if isLoggedIn then do nothing , otherwise bind html data.

Example :

 public ActionResult AddPackage()
    {
       //code here
       ViewBag.isLoggedIn= true or false;
       return View("_PartialEditPackage", objModelView);
    }

  $("#btnCreatePackage").on("click", function () {
        var url = $(this).data("url");
        $.get(url, function (data) {

         if(@ViewBag.isLoggedIn==false)
         {
            $('#createPackageContainer').html(data);
            $('#createPackageModal').modal('show');
         }
        });

    });
```